# How to get H1,H2,H3,... using a single xpath expression

Tags: xpath

How can I get H1,H2,H3 contents in one single xpath expression?

I know I could do this.

```
//html/body/h1/text()
//html/body/h2/text()
//html/body/h3/text()
```

and so on.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/html/body/*[self::h1 or self::h2 or self::h3]/text()
```

**The following expression is incorrect**:

```
//html/body/*[local-name() = "h1"  
           or local-name() = "h2"  
           or local-name() = "h3"]/text()
```

because it may select text nodes that are children of `unwanted:h1`, `different:h2`, `someWeirdNamespace:h3`.

**Another recommendation: Always avoid using `//`** when the structure of the XML document is statically known. Using `//` most often results in significant inefficiencies because it causes the complete document (sub)tree roted in the context node to be traversed.

Comment: On the performance question, your mileage may vary. Some products go to great lengths to optimise queries using //x.

Comment: I want to get the text inside the p tag. The h tag can be h3 or h4 or h5

<div class="content"><h3>Ingredients:</h3><p >Tomato Purée, Acidity Regulator (Citric Acid)</p>

How to get it using a single xpath.?? thanks in advance

Comment: @AswinSathyan, Just ask a separate question at SO.

Comment: great! I needed a descendant selector under body to get all headings: `/html/body//*[self::h1 or self::h2 or self::h3]/text()`