# parsing html using lxml

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have the follow html code

```
<a name="Audio-Encoders"></a>
<h1 class="chapter"><a href="ffmpeg.html#toc-Audio-Encoders">14. Audio Encoders</a></h1>

<p>A description of some of the currently available audio encoders
follows.
</p>
<a name="ac3-and-ac3_005ffixed"></a>
<h2 class="section"><a href="ffmpeg.html#toc-ac3-and-ac3_005ffixed">14.1 ac3 and     ac3_fixed</a></h2>

<p>AC-3 audio encoders.
</p>
<p>These encoders implement part of ATSC A/52:2010 and ETSI TS 102 366, as well as
the undocumented RealAudio 3 (a.k.a. dnet).
</p>
<p>The <var>ac3</var> encoder uses floating-point math, while the <var>ac3_fixed</var>
encoder only uses fixed-point integer math. This does not mean that one is
always faster, just that one or the other may be better suited to a
particular system. The floating-point encoder will generally produce better
quality audio for a given bitrate. The <var>ac3_fixed</var> encoder is not the
default codec for any of the output formats, so it must be specified explicitly
using the option <code>-acodec ac3_fixed</code> in order to use it.
</p>
<a name="AC_002d3-Metadata"></a>
<h3 class="subsection"><a href="ffmpeg.html#toc-AC_002d3-Metadata">14.1.1 AC-3     Metadata</a></h3>

<p>The AC-3 metadata options are used to set parameters that describe the audio,
but in most cases do not affect the audio encoding itself. Some of the options
do directly affect or influence the decoding and playback of the resulting
bitstream, while others are just for informational purposes. A few of the
options will add bits to the output stream that could otherwise be used for
audio data, and will thus affect the quality of the output. Those will be
indicated accordingly with a note in the option list below.
</p>
<p>These parameters are described in detail in several publicly-available
documents.
</p><ul>
```

How the text could be extracted from every after `<hX class="foobar">`?

for example  `<h1 class="chapter">`
the content after h1 tag is "A description of some of the currently available audio encoders
follows."

Comment: That is invalid HTML you have there.

Comment: I changed the question to make it more clear, thank you for reply

Comment: That's hardly any clearer; please make your question self-contained, and not dependent on another website (that may or may not change over time, making your question invalid).

Comment: I Changed the question again for a self-contained question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get H1,H2,H3,... using a single xpath expression](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7992726)

Comment: ffmpeg documentation is available in TextInfo format (http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=tree;f=doc) which is much easier to parse than generated HTML.

Comment: import lxml.html

from lxml.html import fromstring
import urllib

code   = urllib.urlopen("http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html").read()
html = fromstring(code)
result = html.xpath('/html/body/*[self::h1 or self::h2 or self::h3]/text()')
print result

Comment: the code above doesn't help me

Comment: I don't want the h1 content I want the text that is after the tag, that text isn't inside the h1 tag,  Martijn Pieters that link doesn't help and is not related with my question

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
/*/h1/following-sibling::p
         [name(preceding-sibling::*[starts-with(name(),'h')][1])
         = 'h1'
         ]//text()
```

**Evaluating this XPath expression against the following XML document** (obtained from the non-well-formed provided fragment bu deleting the trailing unclosed `ul` and wrapping the result into a single top element):

```
<html>
    <a name="Audio-Encoders"></a>
    <h1 class="chapter">
        <a href="ffmpeg.html#toc-Audio-Encoders">14. Audio Encoders</a>
    </h1>
    <p>A description of some of the currently available audio encoders follows. </p>
    <a name="ac3-and-ac3_005ffixed"></a>
    <h2 class="section">
        <a href="ffmpeg.html#toc-ac3-and-ac3_005ffixed">14.1 ac3 and     ac3_fixed</a>
    </h2>
    <p>AC-3 audio encoders. </p>
    <p>These encoders implement part of ATSC A/52:2010 and ETSI TS 102 366, as well as the undocumented RealAudio 3 (a.k.a. dnet). </p>
    <p>The 
        <var>ac3</var> encoder uses floating-point math, while the 
        <var>ac3_fixed</var> encoder only uses fixed-point integer math. This does not mean that one is always faster, just that one or the other may be better suited to a particular system. The floating-point encoder will generally produce better quality audio for a given bitrate. The 
        <var>ac3_fixed</var> encoder is not the default codec for any of the output formats, so it must be specified explicitly using the option 
        <code>-acodec ac3_fixed</code> in order to use it. 
    </p>
    <a name="AC_002d3-Metadata"></a>
    <h3 class="subsection">
        <a href="ffmpeg.html#toc-AC_002d3-Metadata">14.1.1 AC-3     Metadata</a>
    </h3>
    <p>The AC-3 metadata options are used to set parameters that describe the audio, but in most cases do not affect the audio encoding itself. Some of the options do directly affect or influence the decoding and playback of the resulting bitstream, while others are just for informational purposes. A few of the options will add bits to the output stream that could otherwise be used for audio data, and will thus affect the quality of the output. Those will be indicated accordingly with a note in the option list below. </p>
    <p>These parameters are described in detail in several publicly-available documents. </p>
</html>
```

**Selects the wanted text nodes** (just one in this case):

```
A description of some of the currently available audio encoders follows.
```

**Similarly, this XPath expression**:

```
/*/h2/following-sibling::p
         [name(preceding-sibling::*[starts-with(name(),'h')][1])
         = 'h2'
         ]//text()
```

**Selects these text nodes**:

```
AC-3 audio encoders. These encoders implement part of ATSC A/52:2010 and ETSI TS 102 366, as well as the undocumented RealAudio 3 (a.k.a. dnet). The 
        ac3 encoder uses floating-point math, while the 
        ac3_fixed encoder only uses fixed-point integer math. This does not mean that one is always faster, just that one or the other may be better suited to a particular system. The floating-point encoder will generally produce better quality audio for a given bitrate. The 
        ac3_fixed encoder is not the default codec for any of the output formats, so it must be specified explicitly using the option 
        -acodec ac3_fixed in order to use it.
```

**And finally, this XPath expression**:

```
/*/h3/following-sibling::p
         [name(preceding-sibling::*[starts-with(name(),'h')][1])
         = 'h3'
         ]//text()
```

**selects these text nodes**:

```
The AC-3 metadata options are used to set parameters that describe the audio, but in most cases do not affect the audio encoding itself. Some of the options do directly affect or influence the decoding and playback of the resulting bitstream, while others are just for informational purposes. A few of the options will add bits to the output stream that could otherwise be used for audio data, and will thus affect the quality of the output. Those will be indicated accordingly with a note in the option list below. These parameters are described in detail in several publicly-available documents.
```

Comment: thank you for the amazing answer, but I am trying to do something like that  http://bpaste.net/show/v1xL6rDXJ16LedIm3Gm5/ with xpath

Comment: @PerguntasEasy, Then just remove the string `//text()` that is at the end of each expression.